# Different session time out for different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-timeout

Is it possible to have different session time outs for different users? I need to have 180 mins session for admin and 20 min for non-admin users.
Currently it is single session timeout for all the users. we are using a web.config key

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1571336.aspx/1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting `Session.Timeout` property by code will set the timeout on a per user basis.

You can manually set `Session.Timeout = 20;` or `Session.Timeout = 180;` based on the user type when they log in.

This code should work for you:

```
protected void SetSessionTime(string userType)
{
    if (UserType == "admin")
    {
        Session.Timeout = 180;
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Timeout = 20;
    }
}
```

You can call `SetSessionTime()` after user successfully logs in.