# Session should not expire if user chooses the option

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I want to create as option for user that in my asp.net solution that if user checks for  session should not expire automatically.

Can any one help me on that?

Comment: You could perform a background ajax call every N minutes if the user has checked the option "session should not expire", setting a simple session value or something like that. You coukd also consider storing the sessions in db, rather than InProc for more handling if the browser closes etc.

Comment: upon checking give **Session.Timeout = "SomeBigNumber"**...

Comment: @GopeshSharma Updating the Session Timeout will lead to session timeout increase for everybody that is not what is required i guess

Comment: @devesh thats correct

Comment: @ArjunSharma and Devesh `Session["SessionObjName"]=username; if(USERCHECKS){Session["SessionObjName"].TimeOut = Int32.Max}`

Comment: @GopeshSharma : Thanks for the update , I agree Setting Session.Timeout can be used to increase Session Time out for invidual session per user , check here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152026/different-session-time-out-for-different-users

Comment: @Devesh I agree...thanks for the link, I hope this will help Arjun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set session timeout value but to expire it later you can set it to max value according to below sample.

You can manually set Session.Timeout = 20; or Session.Timeout = 180; based on the user type when they log in.

This code should work for you:

```
protected void SetSessionTime(string userType)
{
    if (UserType == "admin")
    {
        Session.Timeout = Int32.Max;
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Timeout = 20;
    }
}
```

You can call SetSessionTime() after user successfully logs in.

Answer (score 1):

You could try executing a background ajax call (every x minutes) to keep the session alive for users that have chosen to do so.